# How to raise an exception when unpermitted parameters are submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found this bit of code [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html):

```
ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

I tried putting this in `config/environments/development.rb`, but it didn't seem to work. Where should I put it? (I only want this for development env.)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Put this into `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

this will raise `ActionController::UnpermittedParameters`