# How to get strong parameters to raise exception for unknown attribute

Tags: ruby, strong-parameters

`params.require(:xxx).permit(:a, :b, :c)` works halfway for me, that is if `params[:xxx][:d]` is there, it is removed by `permit`. I would like to have an exception though.

Either I did not find the documentation for that, or it is lacking. What option do I set (I would prefer one global setting) to get an exception in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well since you don't have any method that raise an exception, you can use the `permitted?` method to check if it's permitted and raise an exception if the method returns `false`.

EDIT: Actually you can raise an exception with:
`ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise`

more info at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Will accept after a short period.

Comment: It's been 9 months now.

Comment: To get this to work, I had to set it with `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19486025/2200277